# Is there a specific name for this normalization function?

Tags: iphone, function, methods, normalization, method-names

I want to write a normalization function that will take a signed integer and normalize it to a double between -1 to +1. Is there a special name for this type of function, or is `Normalize()` what people normally call it?

Also, is there a native iPhone function that does this?

Comment: "native iPhone function"?? Do you mean "division"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed called normalization. There's no function needed for it since all that's required is to scale it by the maximum and clip it to the range.